# iOS app how to manipulate javascript file

Tags: ios, frida

There is an iOS app that loads few .js file which instantiates global javascript variables ex.

/utils.js

```
window.var1 = 'some data'
```

The following JS file gets called in the app ( I was able to identify this simply by using mitmproxy ).

I am familiar with Frida, how do I go on about executing these global variable and reading its value in a phone environment? Is this possible through frida?

Frida lets me call classes/methods in Objective C, but this is a simple javascript file does frida support this?

Comment: If it is executed within a WebView you can execute it's `evaluateJavaScript` method and inject your own JavaScript code.

Comment: Will I be able to simply do console.log(window.var1) within the function evaluateJavascript?

Comment: Or you use the `completionHandler` callback parameter and return the data as `result`.